# java window update is delayed, how to get fast response?

Tags: java, repaint

I've written a simple java application that drives a display (full screen). It reads instructions from a socket and uses them to update various JLabels. It's pretty trivial: it's just a couple dozen JLabels, each one in its own JPanel. The process() function for the worker is just a few lines long; all it does it is pick up simple instructions sent by doInBackground(), and the instructions are always: a setText() and color on a chosen label, a setBackground on the associated jPanel, and in rare cases it sets a JPanel visible or invisible.

In short, nothing tricky, and an the end of the process loop there's a panel.repaint() and a frame.repaint() call to nudge things along.

Instructions arrive over the socket (which has NODELAY set, and the messages coming over the socket are from a process on the same hardware in this case) at frequent internals, sometimes as fast as 5 or so a second to get a blink effect.

Everything gets painted, but something is buffering/delaying the screen updates. A lot. Things that should blink quickly either won't blink or blink intermittently, evidence that the update commands have piled up and happen in bursts, making some changes effectively invisible. I estimate there's 300ms or more of lag, and this is a case where 20ms is about all I want to see.
The CPU isn't busy and the app doesn't use a lot of CPU (generally 1%, higher than I like but not a problem.)

When I wave the mouse pointer over the window, things speed up.

In short, when I can repaint(), I want it to happen now. I thought repaint ensured that but it doesn't. Suggestions?

Edit, For the curious:
There is a thread that reads from a socket, figures out what is meant and puts the result into a LinkedBlockingQueue. (This is for the day when multiple sockets feed this app). doInBackground is very simple; it just takes from the queue. Unless LinkedBlockingQueue has weird delays, which I would not expect, this shouldn't be the problem. And nothing but process() updates the GUI.

```java
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
     try {
      publish(new Displayable("")); //get started
      for (;;) {
        //read from queue
        publish(General.queue.take());
      }
     } catch (Throwable ex)
     {
        General.fatal(ex);
     }
     return null;
   }
```

Comment: Which operating system is your computer running?

Comment: Are you making sure that your socket is in its own thread and that you are only updating the swing gui in the swing thread?

Comment: Yes, updating the question to show this.

Comment: This is on Linux but I'd hope to all mercy that in something this simple that won't matter.

Comment: Unix systems have problems with Swing painting that Windows systems don't.  Your question is the third one I've seen on Stack Overflow in four months about Unix Swing painting.

Comment: I'd like to believe that the java community on linux is large enough that systemic delays in GUI updates would raise a large hue and cry. You're really saying you think that this is not user error? I was expecting "oh, you just need to..." and not "java is hopelessly slow."